# How do i do a mod_rewrite in xampp localhost in a sub directory?

Tags: xampp

I'm a complete newbie to htaccess and I'm having a problem getting the mod_rewrite to work.

I'm trying to change the below:

http://localhost/login/sitepage.php?linklabel=editted

to

http://localhost/login/sitepage/editted

I've looked at loads of solutions online and none of them work. I've used phpinfo() and mod_rewrite is loaded and I've been able to direct the users to a 404.php file with the htaccess file.

any help would be great thanks**

Answer (score 0):

hey guys sorry for the bother there wasn't actually a problem it was just me being really dumb. I misunderstood what mod_rewrite actually did in that i thought it rewrote the url in the bar when you clicked on a link that displays the query in the url bar.

For anyone who has came across the same problem here's the problem and solution:

i wanted this /sitepage.php?linklabel=editted to change to /editted.html

anyway using the code generator at http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ ,  in the .htaccess file i put the follwing code -

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*).html$ /sitepage.php?linklabel=$1 [L]

When i clicked the button it still went to /sitepage.php?linklabel=editted

I forgot to change [editted page](/sitepage.php?linklabel=editted)

to

[editted page](/editted.html)  because it displays the content from the /sitepage.php?linklabel=editted  page in the new url.

Comment: /editted.html  because it displays the content from the /sitepage.php?linklabel=editted  page in the new url.